# Using best_in_place gem in 2 level nested controllers: [Raven] User excluded error: #<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

I use the gem Best In place for editing discussion topics and comments... It works for Discussion but for Comments it gives record not found error: 
 my routes:
    namespace :school do
     resource :account, :except => [:new, :create, :destroy], :controller => 'account'
     resources :classes, :path => "" do
       resources :discussions do
         resources :comments
       end
     end
    end

show.html.haml (Discussion)

```
  = best_in_place @discussion, :name, :type => :textarea, :path => school_class_discussion_path
  = best_in_place c, :body, :type => :textarea , :path =>school_class_discussion_comment_path(params[:class_id], @discussion)
```

discussion_controler.rb

```
def update
  @discussion.update_attributes(params[:discussion])
  respond_with @discussion
end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
def update
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
 respond_with @comment , :location => school_class_discussion_comment_path(params[:class_id], @discussion))
end
```

I can click on comments and edit but does not update :( log error:
[Raven] User excluded error:ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound comment with id = **actually gives discussion id**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you maybe show us your `show` contorller action for discussion?

I guess that something like this might solve your problem:

```
= best_in_place @discussion, :name, :type => :textarea, :path => school_class_discussion_path(params[:class_id], @discussion)
= best_in_place c, :body, :type => :textarea , :path =>school_class_discussion_comment_path(params[:class_id], @discussion, c)
```